# How to handle column name which contain hash(#) when create native query?

Tags: java, jpa

```
em.createNativeQuery("SELECT u##compid FROM company").getResultList()
```

The above native query(No entity class) throw PersistenceException due to the u##compid column. Other columns wihtout '##' is working fine but this. Is there anyway to overcome?

> Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: java.lang.NullPointerException     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:484)

Comment: try escaping the # with a backslash \ or quote the tablename with backticks ` - for example u\#\#compid or \`u##compid\`

Comment: Both are working!! Thank you so much.